# how to fill gridview with checkboxes in asp.net using vb

Tags: asp.net

i have a gridview with pregenerated columns

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
            BackColor="White" BorderColor="#336666" BorderStyle="Double" BorderWidth="3px" 
            CellPadding="4" GridLines="Horizontal">
            <RowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#333333" />
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="MenuID" >
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("MenuID") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="MenuParentID" >
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("MenuParentID") %>' ></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Particulars">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Particulars") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <ItemStyle Width="250px" />
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Options" HeaderText="Options" 
                    ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" >
<ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"></ItemStyle>
                </asp:BoundField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Menu(M)" >
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkMenu" runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="chkMenu_CheckedChanged" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Add(A)">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkAdd" runat="server" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Edit(E)">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkEdit" runat="server" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Delete(D)">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkDelete" runat="server" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
            <FooterStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#333333" />
            <PagerStyle BackColor="#336666" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#339966" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#336666" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        </asp:GridView>
```

want to fill the grid from database and check/uncheck the checkboxes from database condition. How to fill the gridview ...................................................................................

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On which condition you want to check /Un-check the  chechbox?

you can write code on  RowDataBound event  of grid.

void CustomersGridView_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
  {

```
if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
{


 // here  check the condition and find the check box of current row and set it checked/uncheked

}
```

}